# Intent for Menu Item Buttons

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a button in my action bar and I want when user clicked on that button it shows another activity like intent for normal buttons. That's my main activity :

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.item, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.exit:
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setMessage("میخوای از برنامه بری بیرون؟")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("اره :(",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                finish();


            }

        }).setNegativeButton("نه :)", null).show();

        case R.id.info:








}



    return true; }}
```

I want intent for that case R.id.info:  I have tried this code :

```
case R.id.info:
    public void on click(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,Info.class);
       start activity(intent);
       }
```

but it doesn't work and it shows some errors

please some one help me :(

Comment: Can you give more info on the errors?  Looks like your code won't even compile!

Comment: * it shows some errors*. Can you share that

Comment: @LukeSleeman  http://8pic.ir/images/hlmw3lp02ymiv7l8fu59.jpeg

Comment: @PHELAT Only one comment with the link is enough, they can read it both ;)

Comment: @Strider OK thanks bro I'm new in this website ;)

Comment: It looks like a compile error, not anything to do with android or intents.  I suggest you work on improving your understanding of java.  In particular it seems that your are trying to define a method from inside a case statement ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` to:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case  case R.id.exit:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage("میخوای از برنامه بری بیرون؟")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("اره :(",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("نه :)", null).show();
            break;

        case R.id.info:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Info.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: when I click on info button it shows force close error with this code :(

Comment: @PHELAT Edit your code with this, and add logcat plz, so we know what error we are dealing with.

Comment: Actually your code is correct, problem was some where else. thank you so much you ;)

Comment: @PHELAT Good to hear that you figured it out, and glad I could help, gl ;)

Answer (score 2):

Register your activity in manifest.xml

the class name should be in android:name

```
<activity
      android:name=".ToActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">          
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use this, hope it works for you:

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
    }


    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.info:
                     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?